# bug in content warning page

Tags: javascript, php

I'm helping to my friend a little with debugging his site, I'm not that familiar with php though so I could use some help.

```
if (has_nav_menu('header menu')) {
    ht_header_menu_wp_nav(); // Header Menu
}else{
    echo '<nav id="header-menu">';
    echo '<ul>';
    ht_no_wp_nav_notice();
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</nav>';
}

ht_top_social_media();
ht_top_search_from();

$url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$server=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$str=strstr($url,'www.sample.com');
if($str==""){
?>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#popup").show();
  $("#warningpop").show();
});
</script>
<?php 
}
```

It's a code for a content warning page, meaning that in the first time you enter the page: popup and warningpop are shown, the second time when you press the enter button the HTTP_REFER should be the address of the site and not show popup and warningpop.
The thing is when you press enter you see popup and warningpop so you can't access the content of the site.
Could someone tell me why? 
Thanks :)

Comment: use sessions instead. if you insist on using the referer then use `strpos` instead of `strstr`

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
I could use sessions, I read that HTTP_REFERER can be blocked by some browser which is the case in my opinion.
I thought about starting a sessions and changing the value of a variable when the enter button was clicked, however I have no idea how can I check such a thing, the entire text and the button itself(it's just a text with ref) are written in HTML5 above this code.